# Spring ResponseStatusException does not return reason

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, error-handling

I have a very simple `@RestController`, and I'm trying to set a custom error message. But for some reason, the `message` for the error is not showing up.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("openPharmacy")
public class OpenPharmacyController {


    @PostMapping
    public String findNumberOfSurgeries(@RequestBody String skuLockRequest) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "This postcode is not valid");
    }

}
```

This is the response that I get:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-24T17:44:20.194+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/openPharmacy/"
}
```

I'm passing a JSON, but I'm not validating anything, I'm just trying to set the custom message. If I change the status code, I see that on the response, but the `message` is always empty.

Why is this not working like expected? This is such a simple example that I can't see what may be missing. When I debug the code I can see that the error message has all the fields set. But for some reason, the message is never set on the response.

Comment: I have the same problem, but only when I run the jar. It doesn't happen when the application is started with `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: I managed to get the message to display by putting `server.error.include-message=always` in application.properties as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62467065/3729391).

Comment: @Hassan Please add your comment as an answer so we can upvote it :)

Comment: `server.error.include-message=always` worked for me as well. I also realized that this problem only happens with version `3.0` onwards, if I use an older version I don't need to add anything to `application.properties`

Comment: @Oo.oO It's cool, you can upvote the original answer so that it gains visibility

Comment: @Hassan I upvoted another random answer of yours..

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This answer was provided by user Hassan in the comments on the original question. I'm only posting it as an answer to give it better visibility.

Basically, all you need to do is add `server.error.include-message=always` to your application.properties file, and now your message field should be populated.

This behavior was changed in Spring Boot 2.3 which you can read about here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content

Comment: I think setting `server.error.include-message=always` could be a problem because it als disclosure messages of internal exceptions (like IllegalStateException) !!!

Comment: @MarkusHettich I agree, that's why you should always have an exception handler that catches Exception which then converts the error message into a generic 500 response.

Comment: For security reasons, you should never activate this option in production environment to mitigate potential sensitive information disclosures.

Comment: Also note that it returns the message in the response body and only if the body can be encoded with one of the supported encoders. My request included the header `Accept: application/ion` and then it couldn't serialize the error anymore and it was left out. Changing the request's Accept header into `Accept: application/json, application/ion` fixed the issue. It returned JSON in case of error and ION otherwise.

Comment: I love Spring, but this is a blunder IMO.

Comment: How does the "on_param" works ? It's a param in the exception, in the endpoint... ?

Answer (score 12):

I have the very same issue. If I use this construct

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Error in update");
```

My message is not passed to client via `JSON`. For me, the only way to go around it was to create `GlobalExceptionHandler` class

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import java.util.Date;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
  @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> generateNotFoundException(NotFoundException ex) {
    ErrorDTO errorDTO = new ErrorDTO();
    errorDTO.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    errorDTO.setStatus(String.valueOf(ex.getStatus().value()));
    errorDTO.setTime(new Date().toString());

    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO>(errorDTO, ex.getStatus());
  }
}
```

I have also created my own `Exception` type

```
package mypackage;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

public class NotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

  public NotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public HttpStatus getStatus() {
    return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  }
}
```

With this, I am able to throw exception from the controller and I am getting proper result in `JSON` - the message I want to see.

```
@PutMapping("/data/{id}")
public DataEntity updateData(@RequestBody DataEntity data, @PathVariable int id) {
  throw new NotFoundException("Element not found");
}
```

I had to introduce `ErrorDTO` as well

```
package mypackage;

public class ErrorDTO {
  public String status;
  public String message;
  public String time;

  ...
  ...
  // getters and setters are here 
  ...
  ...
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @Hassan and @cunhaf (in comments under original question), the solution with

```
server.error.include-message=always
```

works perfectly fine with `ResponseStatusException`. Still, solution with `GlobalExceptionHandler` might be better in case someone wants to pass more info via Exception.

**Source code**

Samples can be found here: [Global Exception Handler](https://github.com/mkowsiak/global-exception-handler)

Comment: Thanks, most adapted solution

Answer (score 9):

For those who are concerned about potentially leaking sensitive information with the application.properties recommended by the accepted answer, I found that there are additional options available for the `server.error.include-message` property.

Setting `server.error.include-message=always` will always include a reason when an exception is thrown, even if that reason potentially exposes sensitive information about your application.

A better option to use is `server.error.include-message=on-param`, which will only include a message when you explicitly set one via `ResponseStatusException`:

```
if (requestBody.someField == null) {
   throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "someField is required.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, Spring Boot 2.6.x changed this behavior again and the error message set on `ResponseStatusException` is not returned. I had to downgrade to 2.5.6 in order to solve it. In the end I had something like this:

```
 @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)  
public MessageResponse deleteById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
    try {
        userService.deleteById(id); 
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED, "Error deleting user. User has dependencies", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270993/error-response-body-is-empty-in-spring-boot-2-6 ?

Answer (score 2):

there is bean that can be overridden to include custom message.

Normal Spring Boot: `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes`

Spring Wedbflux: `org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes`

---

the default implementation is `DefaultErrorAttributes`.

You can override
`public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {`

the return make it return the `message` you want

---

In my case I created a decorator that will remove messages if it's internal server error:

```
public class CustomErrorAttributesDecorator implements ErrorAttributes {

    private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;
    
    CustomErrorAttributesDecorator(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes){
        this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {
        Map<String, Object> errorAttributesMap = this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(request, options);
        if(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() == (int) errorAttributesMap.get("status")){
            errorAttributesMap.remove("message");
        }
        return errorAttributesMap;
    }

...
}
```

and then I created a @Bean as follows:

```
        @Bean
        ErrorAttributes customErrorAttributes(){
            return new CustomErrorAttributesDecorator(new DefaultErrorAttributes());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the 2.3 version, Spring Boot doesn't include an error message on the default error page. The reason is to reduce the risk of leaking information to a client

To change the default behavior, we can use a `server.error.include-message` property.

Answer (score 0):

if you are making a REST API take a look at zalando-problem for exception handling. [problem-spring-web](https://github.com/zalando/problem-spring-web)

Evry exception is catched by @ExceptionHandler and you just have to return a Problem object using the zalando builder.

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends Exception {
    // ...
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler implements ProblemHandling {

    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<Problem> handleResourceNotFoundException(final ResourceNotFoundException exception, final NativeWebRequest request) {
        Problem problem = Problem.builder()//
            .withType(URI.create("https://example.com/problem/not-found"))//
            .withTitle("Resource not found")//
            .withStatus(Status.NOT_FOUND)//
            .withDetail(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
        
 ...
}
```