# Spring Reactive WebFlux - how to customize the BadRequest error message

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-reactive

In my request handler, if the passed-in `accountId` cannot be converted to a valid `ObjectId` I want to catch the error and send back a meaningful message; however, doing so causes the return type to be incompatible, and I cannot figure out how to achieve this pretty trivial use case.

My code:

```
  @GetMapping("/{accountId}")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Account>> get(@PathVariable String accountId) {
      log.debug(GETTING_DATA_FOR_ACCOUNT, accountId);

      try {
        ObjectId id = new ObjectId(accountId);
        return repository.findById(id)
            .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()));
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        log.error(MALFORMED_OBJECT_ID, accountId);
        // TODO(marco): find a way to return the custom error message. This seems to be currently
        //  impossible with the Reactive API, as using body(message) changes the return type to
        //  be incompatible (and Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> does not seem to cut it).
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build());
      }
  }
```

The `body(T body)` method changes the type of the returned `Mono` so that it is (assuming one just sends a `String`) a `Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>`; however, changing the method's return type to `Mono<ResponseEntity<?>>` does not work either:

```
        ...
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(
            MALFORMED_OBJECT_ID.replace("{}", accountId)));
```

as it gives an "incompatible type" error on the other `return` statement:

```
error: incompatible types: Mono<ResponseEntity<Account>> cannot be converted to Mono<ResponseEntity<?>>
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()));
```

Obviously, changing the return type of the method to `Mono<?>` would work, but the response then is the serialized JSON of the `ResponseEntity` which is NOT what I want.

I have also tried using the `onErrorXxxx()` methods, but they do not work here either, as the conversion error happens even before the Flux is computed, and I just get a "vanilla" 400 error with an empty message.

The only way I can think of working around this would be to add a `message` field to my `Account` object and return that one, but it's genuinely a horrible hack.

Comment: you need to read up on the basics of reactive programming. You should not use `try/catch`, if you wish to return an error to the client should return a `Mono.error` containing a `ResponseStatusException`. I suggest reading the getting started guide in the reactor documentation. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@thomas-andolf's answer helped me figure out the actual solution.

For anyone stumbling upon this in future, here is how I actually solved the puzzle (and, yes, you still need the `try/catch` to intercept the error thrown by the `ObjectId` constructor):

```
  @GetMapping("/{accountId}")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Account>> get(@PathVariable String accountId) {
    return Mono.just(accountId)
        .map(acctId -> {
          try {
            return new ObjectId(accountId);
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
                MALFORMED_OBJECT_ID));
          }
        })
        .flatMap(repository::findById)
        .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.notFound().build()));
  }
```

To actually see the `message` in the returned body, you will need to add `server.error.include-message=always` in `application.properties` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62561211/spring-responsestatusexception-does-not-return-reason)).

Using `onError()` won't work here (I did try that, in all its variants) as it requires a `Mono<ResponseEntity<Account>>` and there is no way to generate one from the error status (when adding the message body).

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, I literally tried the code in the "accepted" answer and it doesn't compile (nor it does what I intended to do in my original question).  This one compiles and does return the error message to the caller.

Comment: I had the same issue and your question helped to solve mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413913/2096986). your solution with try/catch works although it is not using the functional style which is the best choice since you are using reactive programming.

Comment: glad it helped, @Felipe - if it did, please do upvote it, so it will help others: someone (who didn't even bother to comment and explain themselves) down-voted it, so it shows lower than the (upvoted, but incorrect) one.
As I mention also above, the `try/catch` is *necessary* here because the library method I'm calling does not use functional/reactive style: that method is given and cannot be modified; _not_ using a `try/catch` here causes the exception to propagate and breaks the reactive functional chain.