# How to return bad request in spring webflux when there is an error?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have this server endpoint using `spring-webflux` and I would like to return `ServerResponse.badRequest()` when the `serverRequest` receives a wrong parameter. The request `curl -s "http://localhost:8080/4?a=5&b=3"; echo` for instance, contains the right parameters. But the request `curl -s "http://localhost:8080/one?a=5&b=3"; echo` contains a string instead of an Integer. Then the conversion `new BidRequest(Integer.parseInt(tuple2.getT1()), tuple2.getT2().toSingleValueMap())` will throw an error.

I was doing `.onErrorReturn(new BidRequest(0, null))` but now I want to implement some operation that return `ServerResponse.badRequest()`. So I added in the end `.onErrorResume(error -> ServerResponse.badRequest().build())` in the end, but It is not working. I also added on the place of the code `.onErrorReturn()` and it does not compile.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> bidRequest(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    var adId = serverRequest.pathVariable("id");
    var attributes = serverRequest.queryParams();
    log.info("received bid request with adID: {} attributes: {}", adId, attributes);

    return Mono.just(Tuples.of(adId, attributes))
        .map(tuple2 -> new BidRequest(Integer.parseInt(tuple2.getT1()), tuple2.getT2().toSingleValueMap()))
        // I WANT TO REPLACE IT FOR A BAD REQUEST
        // .onErrorReturn(new BidRequest(0, null))
        .flatMap(bidRequest -> {
            return Flux.fromStream(bidderService.bidResponseStream(bidRequest))
                    .flatMap(this::gatherResponses)
                    .reduce((bidResp1, bidResp2) -> {
                        if (bidResp1.getBid() > bidResp2.getBid()) return bidResp1;
                        else return bidResp2;
                    });
        })
        .map(bid -> {
            var price = bid.getContent().replace("$price$", bid.getBid().toString());
            bid.setContent(price);
            return bid;
        })
        .flatMap(winner -> {
            return ServerResponse.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(winner.getContent()));
        })
        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build())
        // THIS DOES NOT RETURN ANY BAD REQUEST
        .onErrorResume(error -> ServerResponse.badRequest().build());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63684424/2096986) using `flatmap` and returning a `Mono.just()` or a `Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));`.

```
return Mono
        .just(Tuples.of(adId, attributes))
        .flatMap(tuple2 -> {
            if (validate(tuple2)) {
                log.info("request parameters valid: {}", tuple2);
                return Mono.just(new BidRequest(Integer.parseInt(tuple2.getT1()), tuple2.getT2().toSingleValueMap()));
            } else {
                log.error("request parameters invalid: {}", tuple2);
                return Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
            }
        })
        .flatMap(....
```

```
private boolean validate(Tuple2<String, MultiValueMap<String, String>> tuple2) {
    return GenericValidator.isInteger(tuple2.getT1());
}
```