# Spring Security response with error page (403.html) when anyRequest().denyAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, error-handling

I have the following Spring Security (5.6.1) configuration with Spring Boot (2.6.3):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/overview.html").denyAll();
}
```

I also have some error pages located in `/src/main/resources/public/error/`

```
 - 403.html
 - 404.html
 - 4xx.html
 - 5xx.html
```

When I send a request to `/overview.html` I get a 403 error and the content of the `403.html`. So far so good.

When I add an `anyRequest().denyAll()`, I get a 403 error but the response body is empty.

Can anybody explain what's happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error response body is empty in Spring Boot 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70270993/error-response-body-is-empty-in-spring-boot-2-6)

Comment: Thanks @ChinHuang. That was the problem. Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.2 solved the issue for me.